# How to use a join in an insert statement and sql server C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, join

So I have two tables, landlords and property.
I am trying to insert data into my property table which works fine however I have to type the landlord id of whoever is logged in at that time in order for it to work. I was wondering is there a way to use an inner join with an insert statement.

I have previously done this using a select statement like so which shows me all the properties related to the landlord that is logged in:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rent-
dbConnectionString1"].ToString();
con.Open();
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
comm.CommandText = "select p.Property_Id, p.Property_Address, 
p.Property_Num_Of_Tenants, p.Property_Vacant from Properties p inner join 
Landlords l On p.Landlord_Id = l.Landlord_Id where l.Landlord_Id = 
p.Landlord_Id and l.Landlord_Email = '" + checkEmail + "'";
comm.Connection = con;
SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();
```

However, I am unsure how to use it for an insert statement as it is different than a select. This is my insert code at the moment:

```
string cs = 
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["rent-
dbConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Properties(Landlord_Id, 
Property_Address, Property_Num_Of_Tenants, Property_Vacant) values('" + 
this.txtLandlordId.Text + "','" + this.txtPropertyAddress.Text + "','" + 
this.txtNumOfTenants.Text + "','" + this.chkVacant.Checked + "')", con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: The basic query form for using a SELECT in an INSERT statement is the same - you just start with your INSERT statement, e.g. `INSERT INTO MyTable (Field1, Field2, Field3) SELECT IDField, '" + this.Field2Data + "', '" + this.Field3Data + "' FROM MyTable WHERE Fieldx = '" + this.LookupData + "'"`

Comment: Normally you would select the id and then insert it separately. Stored procedures can be handy for this, as you make one call to a procedure on the database and it'll do the select and insert, instead of making two separate calls to the database.  Doing in line commands like that without sanitizing the input is very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Stored Procedure to insert data into Two tables based on Join with primary and Foreign Key reference.

First Create Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spName AS
GO
```

Now Alter Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spName] AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
 SET XACT_ABORT ON;
  insert into Table1(Col1, Col2) values (val1,val2) -- put other values here (from parameters?)
   insert into Table2(Table1primaryKey, col2, col3) values (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), val2, val3) --Scope_Identity() method will get last inserted primary key of first Table and put other values here (from parameters?) instead of Val1,val2 etc.
   
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
    END
```

I hope this will resolve your problem as I it worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming you are doing a Web Forms Application and you have a login for your system since there are multiple landlords that updates a property.

Things to take note and Best Practice:

1) Since you have a login, in ASP.Net there's a global variable called Sessions, you can save the ID or whatever important details of the logged in user you have to save. you can do it like so:

```
Session["landlordId"] = landlord.Id; //landlord is a class and
                                     //Id is the property inside the class
```

2) With sessions no matter what page you are, you can access it by:

```
string loggedUser = (string)(Session["landlordId"]);
                    //Session["landlordId"].ToString(); or like this
```

3) Always use parameterized query for security (to avoid SQL Injection) ex:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Properties(Landlord_Id, 
Property_Address, Property_Num_Of_Tenants, Property_Vacant) values(@landlordID, @propertyAddress, @propertyNumOfTenants, @propertyVacant)", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@landlordID", sqlDbType.Int32).Value = Session["landlordId"].ToString();
//and do the same for other parameters
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

If you follow steps 1 and 2 your problem will no longer be difficult.  And you can do your insert like step 3.  No need for join or complex code just for an insert to a single table.